# searching file having timestamp

Tags: c#

I have a scenario like this in my application.I want to search for a file name which has a time stamp.I have done like:

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\ScriptLog\\ScriptLog_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH") + ".log") == true)
 {
   //tasks
 }
```

But this doesn't seem to be working...Can anyone please support on this?

What I want is that I should be able to search for files created in that hour. Suppose if the present time is 10:43:04, then I should be able to check the files created at 10:00:00 upto now..

Comment: can you show sample file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\ScriptLog")
    .EnumerateFiles("*.log")
    .Where(x => x.CreationTime.Hour >= DateTime.Now.Hour); 

if (files.Any() != null)
{
    // tasks
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\ScriptLog\\", "*.log");
foreach(var file in files)
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
    if(fileInfo.CreationTime >= /*your date here*/)
    {
        //This is the file you are searching for
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me you should get the file list of whole directory, and then check the time stamp.
If you want to check only the current hour then the code will look like:

```
string[] ListFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\ScriptLog\\", "*.log*");
string currHour = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH");

foreach (string s in ListFiles)
{
   if (s.EndsWith(currHour + ".log"))
   {
      //tasks
   }
}
```

j